# Getting 'expected an indented block' and " 'return' outside function" errors

Tags: python

```
def f(x):
x = x + 1 
print 'x =', x
return x 
x = 3 
z = f(x)
print 'z =', z
print 'x =', x
```

I started learning Python.

A problem I keep encountering is an error message stating "Expected an indented block" specifically at line 2. It keeps highlighting the initial x. I researched this problem and a proposed solution was to indent at the threshold of the 2nd line, yet that would result in a message stating " 'return' outside function ".

I tried running it in the python interpreter and a visual one at this link http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit I know this code is incomplete as it is a piece of the puzzle, but I'm trying to walk myself through it and see the output to know what it does. I run Python 2.5.4 and the program is supposed to calculate the square root.

Comment: all lines after return must be written in another function or in main.

Comment: Easy: indent everything what must be indented (i. e., what belongs into the function), and everything to the level needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to indent your code properly. Python uses indentation to figure out which line of code/statement belongs to which logical block. Read mote about it [here](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html).

```
def f(x):
    x = x + 1 
    print 'x =', x
    return x 

x = 3 
z = f(x)
print 'z =', z
print 'x =', x
```

As it currently stands, your code from line2-4 is not indented right, because of which, your return statement appears to be out of place as well.

Comment: I actually bore the entire 10  minutes just to press that accept button. Thanks.